# ASP.NET ambigous match, not control related

Tags: asp.net

Im getting an error, Ambiguous match found, on one of my pages. It does not give any information about any controls or such, just the first line in the .aspx file is mentioned. But, there seems to be no error there. I have looked at the designer file, no conflicts. I have checked the control, no naming conflicts. Not really sure what this is at all?

Anyone?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, turns out I had a HTMLControl and a public variable with the same names. A name change solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we have same id or duplicate id created in page. 
For example if you have a control with id as "ControlID" and if you try to create same id for different variable or control you will get this errror.

Please check your code to see if you have any controls or variables same name for ambiguity.